# PDO OOP PHP - Undefined variable and non-object

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

This is a PHP login script this part is the register part. I coded a user class there is $user->check() function it controls are the form elements empty or something different. But I am new at the PDO and OOP I guess I did something wrong so unfortunately it shows me two error..

One of them is :

> Notice: Undefined variable: DB_con in C:\wamp\www\eva\userclass.php on line 56

The other one is :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\eva\userclass.php on line 56

userclass.php Line 56 :

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_name,user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail");
```

What I am doing wrong ? Here is my all files thanks all from now.

dbconfig.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_name = "dbeva";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "";

try {

    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "<div class='bildirim'>- Veritabanına Bağlandı !</div>";

    }

catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "<div class='bildirim'>- Veritabanı Bağlantısı Başarısız !</div>";

    }

include_once 'userclass.php';
$user = new user($DB_con);

?>
```

userclass.php

```
<?php

    class user {

        private $db;

        function __construct($DB_con) {

            $this->db = $DB_con;
            echo "<div class='bildirim'>- Constructor Çalıştı !</div>";

        }   // Constructor Function

        public function check($cuname,$cumail,$cupass) {

            if ($cuname == "") {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Kullanıcı adı boş bırakılamaz.</div>";

            }   // if $cuname == ""

            else if (strlen($cuname) < 6 && strlen($cuname) > 15) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Kullanıcı adı 6 ile 15 karakter arasında olmalıdır.</div>";

            }   // else if 6 <= $cuname <= 15

            else if ($cumail == "") {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Email boş bırakılamaz.</div>";

            }   // else if $cumail == ""

            else if (!filter_var($cumail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Lütfen geçerli bir mail adresi girin.</div>";

            }   // else if validate email

            else if ($cupass == "") {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Şifre boş bırakılamaz.</div>";

            }   //else if $cupass == ""

            else if (strlen($cupass) < 6) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Şifre en az 6 karakter olmalıdır.</div>";

            }   // else if $upass < 6

            else {

                try {

                    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_name,user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail");
                    $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$cuname, ':umail'=>$cumail));
                    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if($row['user_name'] == $cuname) {

                        echo "<div class='bildirim'>Üzgünüz, kullanıcı adı çoktan alınmış.</div>";

                    }   // if user_name exist

                    else if($row['user_email'] == $cumail) {

                        echo "<div class='bildirim'>Üzgünüz, sitemizde bu mail adresi ile kayıtlı bir üye zaten var.</div>";

                    }   // else if user_email exist

                    else {

                        try {

                            $new_pass = password_hash($cupass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass)
                                                        VALUES(:uname,:umail,:upass)");

                            $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $cuname);
                            $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $cumail);
                            $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_pass);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            return $stmt;

                            echo "<div class='bildirim'>- Kayıt İşlemi Başarılı !</div>";

                        }   // try register

                        catch(PDOException $e) {

                            echo $e->getMessage();
                            echo "<div class='bildirim'>- Kayıt İşlemi Başarısız !</div>";

                        }   // catch register

                    }   // else

                }   // try check

                catch (PDOException $e) {

                    echo $e->getMessage();

                }   // catch check

            }   // else

        }   // Function Check

    }   // User Class

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

    require_once "dbconfig.php";

    if (isset($_POST['btn_signup'])) {

        $r_uname = trim($_POST['r_uname']);
        $r_uname = strip_tags($r_uname);
        $r_umail = trim($_POST['r_umail']);
        $r_umail = strip_tags($r_umail);
        $r_upass = trim($_POST['r_upass']);
        $r_upass = strip_tags($r_upass);

        $user->check($r_uname,$r_umail,$r_upass);

    }   // if isset btn_signup

    if (isset($_POST['btn_login'])) {

        //$user->login();

    }   // if isset btn_signup

?>

<html>
<head>
    <head>
    <title>Eva Login System</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="formwrapper">
        <h2>Giriş Yap !</h2>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input class="inputa" type="text" name="l_umail" placeholder="Email">
            <input class="inputa" type="password" name="l_upass" placeholder="Şifre">
            <input class="inputb" type="submit" name="btn_login" value="Giriş Yap">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="formwrapper">
        <h2>Bize Katıl !</h2>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input class="inputa" type="text" name="r_uname" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı">
            <input class="inputa" type="text" name="r_umail" placeholder="Email">
            <input class="inputa" type="text" name="r_upass" placeholder="Şifre">
            <input class="inputb" type="submit" name="btn_signup" value="Hesap Aç">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit parts that are wrong in your class**

```
 $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_name,user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail");
```

to

```
 $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT user_name,user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail");
```

**Complete Class**

```
class user {

        private $db;

        function __construct($DB_con) {

            $this->db = $DB_con;
            echo "<div class='bildirim'>- Constructor Çalıştı !</div>";

        }   // Constructor Function

        public function check($cuname,$cumail,$cupass) {
            $error = false;
            if (empty($cuname)) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Kullanıcı adı boş bırakılamaz.</div>";
                $error = true;

            }

            if (strlen($cuname) < 6 || strlen($cuname) > 15) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Kullanıcı adı 6 ile 15 karakter arasında olmalıdır.</div>";
                $error = true;
            } 

            if (empty($cumail)) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Email boş bırakılamaz.</div>";
                $error = true;
            } 

            if (!filter_var($cumail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Lütfen geçerli bir mail adresi girin.</div>";
                $error = true;
            } 

            if (empty($cupass)) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Şifre boş bırakılamaz.</div>";
                $error = true;
            }

            if (strlen($cupass) < 6) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Şifre en az 6 karakter olmalıdır.</div>";
                $error = true;
            } 
            if($error==false) {
                try {

                    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT user_name,user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail");
                    $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$cuname, ':umail'=>$cumail));
                    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    if($row['user_name'] == $cuname) {

                        echo "<div class='bildirim'>Üzgünüz, kullanıcı adı çoktan alınmış.</div>";
                        $error = true;
                    }   

                    if($row['user_email'] == $cumail) {

                        echo "<div class='bildirim'>Üzgünüz, sitemizde bu mail adresi ile kayıtlı bir üye zaten var.</div>";
                        $error = true;
                    }  
                    if($error==false) {                 
                        try {

                            $new_pass = password_hash($cupass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_pass)
                                                        VALUES(:uname,:umail,:upass)");

                            $stmt->bindparam(":uname", $cuname);
                            $stmt->bindparam(":umail", $cumail);
                            $stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_pass);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            return $stmt;

                            echo "<div class='bildirim'>- Kayıt İşlemi Başarılı !</div>";

                        }   // try register

                        catch(PDOException $e) {

                            echo $e->getMessage();
                            echo "<div class='bildirim'>- Kayıt İşlemi Başarısız !</div>";

                        }   // catch register
                    }

                }   // try check

                catch (PDOException $e) {

                    echo $e->getMessage();

                }   // catch check

            }

        }   // Function Check

    }   // User Class
```

Comment: you have it correct later on in your insert statement but in select you used $DB_con when $this->db should be used.

Comment: @RiggsFolly full solution will not throw error in line 77

Comment: Look again, the private property does not need changing, not even the way you suggest the second change to be done

Comment: It works thank you. I vote your answer but I have another problem It's so simple but not working.

Here is not working : 

`else if (strlen($cuname) < 6 && strlen($cuname) > 15) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Kullanıcı adı 6 ile 15 karakter arasında olmalıdır.</div>";

            }`

Comment: @Brown Ummm What value can possibly be `less than 6` AND `greater than 15` ??????

Comment: Yes for example 'Riggs' can not be
 'RiggsFolly' can be
 'RiggsFolly123456' can not be

Comment: @Brown i have made some alterations to the class can you check it as it is now?

Comment: @RiggsFolly is right it is `less than 6` OR `greater than 15`

Comment: Natification came now. That's why I could not answer sorry for that :) what kind alternations can I see it?

Comment: Aa sorry I saw your new code now it is super I will change my code like that thank you very much you re so helpful like a teacher :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$DB_con` with `$this->db` in file `C:\wamp\www\eva\userclass.php`,  (line 56).

Comment: actually DB_con is passed to the constructor of the class and assigned to the private variable therefore unless there was an error in the connection to the DB, my suggestion will work

Comment: @PeterDarmis In that case please remove the downvote if it was yours

Comment: It works thank you. I vote your answer but I have another problem It's so simple but not working.

Why here is not working ?

`else if (strlen($cuname) < 6 && strlen($cuname) > 15) {

                echo "<div class='bildirim'>Kullanıcı adı 6 ile 15 karakter arasında olmalıdır.</div>";

            }`

Comment: @Brown Ummm What value can possibly be `less than 6` AND `greater than 15` ?????? Use OR

Comment: @RiggsFolly My suggestion is to be patient as we all have done similar mistakes

Comment: @Brown, you should have an OR instead of the AND since the string length should be either less than 6 OR greater than 15 to fail. else if (strlen($cuname) < 6 || strlen($cuname) > 15) { echo "<div class='bildirim'>Kullanıcı adı 6 ile 15 karakter arasında olmalıdır.</div>"; }

Comment: Aa of course! How I missed that thanks all the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `php.ini` file and find `;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll`  statement.

Then remove the `;` and save the file.

Then restart your Apache server.